# Exception of :Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net, visual-c++, exception, c++-cli

When I try to execute the below code I get `System.NullReferenceException` saying that 
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

```
String^ databasePath;
wchar_t* nativeDataPath;
try{
 if(folderBrowserDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
      {

         databasePath=folderBrowserDialog1->SelectedPath->ToString()+"\\DocData.db3"; 

      }
}
catch (System::IO::DirectoryNotFoundException^ ex){
    MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);

}
```

Comment: In what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, at the menu at the top, click on Debug -> Exceptions. Set "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" to "Thrown". This might make a different exception appear somewhere else which might be the root of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of  `folderBrowserDialog1->SelectedPath` if this is `null` or not.

If this is null, then doing `folderBrowserDialog1->SelectedPath->ToString()` will throw this exception.